# Android studio Firebase how to show other users information?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show a profile page of other users with their data. I have data stored in the Realtime Database. I can load my own data but have do I do that for specific users and show it?

For example the current user I use the following code to get the datasnapshot

```
   firebaseDatabase.getReference("users").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid)
```

Comment: You should be able to get the value of `firebaseDatabase.getReference("users")` which would ive you a list of all your users

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you database is structured but you should be ale to do something like this:

```
val userRef = database.getReference("users")

userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val data = snapshot.value as? Map<String, *>?

        // data is a map of { uid to User }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Loading user data failed: \n" + error.message)
    }
})
```

Basically do it the same way you get the individual user, but pull from the parent node to get all of them in the form of a map